# Need to get current timestamp in Java

Tags: java, datetime, format, timestamp

I need to get the current timestamp in Java, with the format of `MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM`,

For example: `06/01/2000 10:01:50 AM`

I need it to be Threadsafe as well.

Can I utilize something like this?

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Or the examples discussed at the link [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-timestamp-example-current-time-now).

Comment: If you create SimpleDateFormat in the scope of a method it will be threadsafe...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The threadunsafety of `SimpleDateFormat` should not be an issue if you just create it inside the very same method block as you use it. In other words, you are *not* assigning it as static or instance variable of a class and reusing it in one or more methods which can be invoked by multiple threads. Only this way the threadunsafety of `SimpleDateFormat` will be exposed. You can however safely reuse the same `SimpleDateFormat` instance within the very same method block as it would be accessed by the current thread only.

Also, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class which you're using there should not be abused as it's specific to the JDBC API in order to be able to store or retrieve a `TIMESTAMP`/`DATETIME` column type in a SQL database and convert it from/to `java.util.Date`.

So, this should do:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // 12/01/2011 4:48:16 PM
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This worked, thank you!  I appreciate your detailed, concise account of thread safety, with respect to SimpleDateFormat.  You're view on Timestamp is use it exclusively for SQL.  That makes perfect sense.  Thank you for your wisdom.

Answer (score 19):

**Print a Timestamp in java, using the java.sql.Timestamp.**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
 
public class GetCurrentTimeStamp {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
2014-08-07 17:34:16.664
```

**Print a Timestamp in Java using SimpleDateFormat on a one-liner.**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(
            new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

    }

}
```

Prints:

```
08/14/2014 14:10:38
```

**Java date format legend:**

```
G Era designation      Text               AD
y Year                 Year               1996; 96
M Month in year        Month              July; Jul; 07
w Week in year         Number             27
W Week in month        Number             2
D Day in year          Number             189
d Day in month         Number             10
F Day of week in month Number             2
E Day in week          Text               Tuesday; Tue
a Am/pm marker         Text               PM
H Hour in day (0-23)   Number             0
k Hour in day (1-24)   Number             24
K Hour in am/pm (0-11) Number             0
h Hour in am/pm (1-12) Number             12
m Minute in hour       Number             30
s Second in minute     Number             55
S Millisecond          Number             978
z Time zone            General time zone  Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z Time zone            RFC 822 time zone  -0800
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this single line solution :

```
import java.util.Date;
String timestamp = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").format(new Date());
```

Comment: This works. Writing more than 1 line to do something like this seems ridiculous for a modern language.

Comment: @AndrewCowenhoven It is more than 1 line. :D

Answer (score 8):

The fact that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe does not mean you cannot use it.
What that only means is that you must not use a single (potentially, but not necessarily `static`) instance that gets accessed from several threads at once.

Instead, just make sure you create a fresh `SimpleDateFormat` for each thread. Instances created as local variables inside a method are safe by definition, because they cannot be reached from any concurrent threads.

You *might* want to take a look at the `ThreadLocal` class, although I would recommend to just create a new instance wherever you need one. You can, of course, have the format definition defined as a `static final String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "...";` somewhere and use that for each new instance.

Comment: I wish I can give you a checkmark, as well, as you deserve one, too.  Your knowledge of this subject is invaluable to myself and others who will read this question.  Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

As of Java 8+ you can use the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Specifically, use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the patterns and literals.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MM").appendLiteral("/")
        .appendPattern("dd").appendLiteral("/")
        .appendPattern("yyyy").appendLiteral(" ")
        .appendPattern("hh").appendLiteral(":")
        .appendPattern("mm").appendLiteral(":")
        .appendPattern("ss").appendLiteral(" ")
        .appendPattern("a")
        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
```

The output ...

```
06/22/2015 11:59:14 AM
```

Or if you want different [time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)…

```
// system default
System.out.println(formatter.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(Instant.now()));
// Chicago
System.out.println(formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).format(Instant.now()));
// Kathmandu
System.out.println(formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kathmandu")).format(Instant.now()));
```

The output ...

```
06/22/2015 12:38:42 PM
06/22/2015 02:08:42 AM
06/22/2015 12:53:42 PM
```

Comment: We can also use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")` to get an instance of DateTimeFormatter :)

Comment: It’s more wordy than needed. You may use just `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");`. Or if you want to make it very explicit that the literals are literals: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'hh':'mm':'ss' 'a")`- No matter if you use your version or mine, I consider using `java.time` an excellent idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `java.util.Date` with direct date string format:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

## Joda-Time

Here is the same kind of code but using the third-party library [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

In real life, I would specify a [time zone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html), as relying on default zone is usually a bad practice. But omitted here for simplicity of example.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new DateTime();
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" );
String nowAsString = formatter.print( now );

System.out.println( "nowAsString: " + nowAsString );
```

When run…

```
nowAsString: 11/28/2013 11:28:15 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this when I wanted a tmiestamp

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Hope it helps :) As a newbie I think it's self-explanatory.

I think you also need import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; header for it to work :))

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345074/10819573) uses the legacy API (`java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) which was the right thing to do at the time of writing that answer. However, Java-8 brought the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) which supplanted the outdated and error-prone legacy date-time API and their formatting API. Since then it has been highly recommended to switch to the modern API.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.**

Note that `java.time` types are thread-safe.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Format [`LocalDateTime#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) with a `DateTimeFormatter` using the required format.

```
LocalDateTime.now()
             .format(
                 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                     "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

**Notes:**

1. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).
2. [Always specify a `Locale` with a `SimpleDateFormat`, and a `DateTimeFormatter` for custom formats.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573). Note that [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) do not accept Locale (i.e. they work with the system's `Locale`).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the current date-time in your system's time-zone
        // Note: if you want to get the current date-time in a specific time-zone,
        // use LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId)
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        // Default format
        System.out.println(now);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String dtInCustomFormat = now.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(dtInCustomFormat);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2023-11-13T20:54:51.573121
11/13/2023 08:54:51 PM
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/vyvHAI)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Good Answer, as always. The phrasing of "Never use a DateTimeFormatter for custom formats, and a SimpleDateFormat without a Locale." seems awkward. Perhaps turn that around to say "Always specify a `Locale` on your formatter". (a) The positive (always versus never) seems simpler. (b) Shouldn't we specify a locale on all formatters, not just *custom* formatters? Or did I miss your point.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for your valuable advice! I am going to rephrase that sentence. **Regarding `Locale` for custom formats:** The reason why I've mentioned *custom formats* is that [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) do not accept `Locale` (i.e. they work with system's `Locale`).

Comment: Yes, that is an important point! I suggest you mention that explicitly in your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt}", dt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, this did not work.  I got the error of "The method Format(String, Date) is undefined for the type String".  It expects object type, not date type.

Comment: Try with a lower-case "f" for String.format(...).  Method names in java start with a lower-case letter by convention.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried String str = String.format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt}", new Date()); and str takes the value of {0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt}.  That is, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

well sometimes this is also useful.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class DisplayDate {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   // Instantiate an object
   Date date = new Date();

   // display time and date
   System.out.println(date.toString());}}
```

**sample output:** `Mon Jul 03 19:07:15 IST 2017`