# Timestamp/ Date error Java

Tags: java, sql, database, date, timestamp

I have some problems with inserting a TimeStamp into the database(something is wrong with format. The db accepts `dd.MM.yyyy`). When I convert the `Date` to `TimeStamp` and then inserted it into the database, it fails. The format of `TimeStamp` is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345023/need-to-get-current-timestamp-in-java-but-with-format-of-mm-dd-yyyy-hmmss-am-p

Answer (score 1):

If your DB really insists on dd.MM.yyyy and you have no option to use something like `makedate(format, myDateInTheGivenFormat)` then you have to do the reformatting within Java yourself.

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to reformat your date accordingly to the DB's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the java.sql.Date, that can help you