# How to upload different filename and with latest Date/Time stamp using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My code:

```
WebElement choosefile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_flUpload']"));
choosefile.sendKeys("/Users/ExcelFiles/test.xlsx");
```

My question: Here I am only uploading **test.xlsx** file, **If I want to upload different file name with .xlsx extension, which has a latest Date and Time stamp.** Please let me know how to to do that.

Comment: You should use Java's LocalDataTime for this.

Comment: Can you please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345074/8020699) answer shows that you can do this by:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_h:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

WebElement choosefile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_flUpload']"));
choosefile.sendKeys("/Users/ExcelFiles/test" + formattedDate + ".xlsx");
```